# Make image cover outline of parent div

Tags: html, css

I have an image with an offset dashed outline, so it is inside the div. I also have an image inside the div. I would like for the image to cover the outline, however instead the outline is over the image.

How can I make it so that the image is over the outline?

```css
:root {
    --background: #9376e0;
    --main: #f6ffa6;
    --accent: #e892cf;
}

body {
    background-color: var(--background);
}

.center {
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}

.contentbox {
    margin: 0 2rem;
    background-color: var(--main);

    box-shadow: 15px 15px var(--accent);
    border: 4px solid var(--accent);
    border-radius: 10px;
    border-top: 50px solid var(--accent);

    outline: 2px dashed var(--accent);
    outline-offset: -10px;

    padding: 20px 10px 15px 20px;
}

.titlebar {
    margin: -90px -300px 30px -10px;
    min-width: 100%;
}

.titlebar, .titlebar img {
    max-width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<link href="/assets/external/bootstrap-5.0.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<div class="col-lg-8 main">
  <div class="contentbox">
    <h1 class="titlebar">
      <img class="center" src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/255419/pexels-photo-255419.jpeg?cs=srgb&dl=pexels-pixabay-255419.jpg&fm=jpg">
    </h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You could add `position: relative;` to the image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Amaury Hanser gave the right answer, but to be able to accept an answer to your question I will right down the full code below. Add `position: relative` to the image in CSS and it will be on top of the outline.

```css
:root {
    --background: #9376e0;
    --main: #f6ffa6;
    --accent: #e892cf;
}

body {
    background-color: var(--background);
}

.center {
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}

.contentbox {
    margin: 0 2rem;
    background-color: var(--main);

    box-shadow: 15px 15px var(--accent);
    border: 4px solid var(--accent);
    border-radius: 10px;
    border-top: 50px solid var(--accent);

    outline: 2px dashed var(--accent);
    outline-offset: -10px;

    padding: 20px 10px 15px 20px;
}

.titlebar {
    margin: -90px -300px 30px -10px;
    min-width: 100%;
}

.titlebar, .titlebar img {
    max-width: 100%;
}

.titlebar img {
    position: relative;
}
```

```html
<link href="/assets/external/bootstrap-5.0.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<div class="col-lg-8 main">
  <div class="contentbox">
    <h1 class="titlebar">
      <img class="center" src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/255419/pexels-photo-255419.jpeg?cs=srgb&dl=pexels-pixabay-255419.jpg&fm=jpg">
    </h1>
  </div>
</div>
```